# how to create a function inside the class component in angular 13?

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, forms, components

I have code for switch toogle but the problem i cant get rid of the erro says 'unexpected token' its expecting constructor or method within a class. This is Angular component and class that needs to be implements i dont need other files to use to achieve only these two implementation and below this is what i tried.

````
`// code in Angular js 13
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'toggle-button',
template: `
<div class="toggle-button">
    <button (click)="toggleState()">{{ yourVariableName === true ? "ON" : "OFF" }} />
</div>
`})

export class ToggleButton {
    buttonState: boolean = false;

    function toggleState() {
        this.buttonState != this.buttonState;
    }
}`
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sgd8.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your template from this:

```
<div class="toggle-button">
    <button (click)="toggleState()">{{ yourVariableName === true ? "ON" : "OFF" }} />
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="toggle-button">
    <button (click)="toggleState()">{{ yourVariableName === true ? "ON" : "OFF" }}</button>
</div>
```

You have messed up with the button start and end tag. Text "ON" and "OFF" should go between two button tags: `<button></button>`

Comment: thanks i just have done, but now i am not able to see the button from the screen. See below the code compiles fine but no gui to switch on and off button  dont know could be this online IDE

Comment: @SandraJackson, in typescript you not prefix with function in a component. You declare your function like:`toggleState() {this.buttonState != this.buttonState;}`